# Oracle query : Missing Keywords/parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I am executing sql queries in unix. But I didn't identify the error in query.

`CREATE TABLE flights ( route_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
depart_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
arrive_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
base_price_usd NUMBER(17,2) NOT NULL CHECK (base_price_usd > cast(0.0 as clob)::money), 
status_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (route_id, depart_timestamp), 
FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES routes(route_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES route_statuses(status_id) );`

ERROR at line 2:

ORA-00905: missing keyword

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: That fourth line doesn't make sense. Why cast 0 as CLOB? Just make the constraint CHECK base_price_usd>0. Oh, and you can't use a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE column as part of a composite primary key, as far as I know.

Comment: I have change the query but still same error in oracle 8.0.6.3 Query : CREATE TABLE flights ( route_id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, 
depart_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL , 
arrive_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
base_price_usd NUMBER(17,2) NOT NULL CHECK (base_price_usd > 0), 
status_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (route_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (route_id) REFERENCES routes(route_id), 
FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES route_statuses(status_id) );

Comment: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data type was implemented in Oracle 10g. It won't work in Oracle 8.

Comment: Then which datatype I use instead of it.

Comment: You could use a simple DATE data type. If you really need to store time zone, you must migrate at least to Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, posting as anwser:

1) Make your `CHECK` constraint just `CHECK base_price_usd > 0`

2) `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data types can't be used as primary keys.

3) `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` were implemented in Oracle 10g. Since you're using Oracle 8, it won't work there. Use `DATE` type.

I guess you could add a column to store the TIME ZONE. It could be a `VARCHAR2` and store values like 'GMT-6' or something, but I don't see it worth it since more recent versions of Oracle can store it by default.